# Idiomatic functional way to make in memory repository for tests in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, repository

I have a 2 questions.

1. I'm making a backend using Akka typed and wanted to make a tests. Simple approeach, no dependency injection, auto-wiring etc. So I have a trait

```
trait Repository {
  def create(h: Model): Future[Int]

  def get(id: Long): Future[Model]
}
```

So 2 classes are extending the trait - `DatabaseRepository` and `InMemoryRepository`

InMemoryRepository should be used for tests. The simplest solution is to create `mutable.Map` member for storing entities an update it on each create operation. However, that is mutating a state. I know that these are tests, but even in tests there might be a need for concurrently creating entities.

The other, maybe more functional approach to make a create method returns a Tuple (InMemoryRepository, Int) so it can be passed around when composing Futures, or any effects.

Maybe a solution is to create a simple State monad which would store a `Map`, implement `flatMap` method, which can be used in a for comprehension and on all the other places when needed and which hides mutating state.

Do you maybe have a better approach to this?

2. What is the best approach to pass config values around? I created a package object and have a variables there like `dbHost`, `thirdPartyUrl` (loaded from config). Then I include this package object where ever needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single, well documented way, but here is mine. It is a bit long, so I put it on a gist.
Abstracting away the container type, as in my project I use both Future and IO:
https://gist.github.com/V-Lamp/c8862030a2f9bba4951db985b61719b8

Comment: Thanks, that's something what I was going for!

Answer (score 0):

If `InMemoryRepository` is only used for tests, you don't need to implement it at all. Just use a mock.
For example:

```
   val repo = mock[Repository]
   val models = Seq(mock[Model], mock[Model], mock[Model])
   models.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (m,i) => 
      when(repo.create(m)).thenReturn(Future.successful(i+1))
      when(repo.get(i+1)).thenReturn(Future.successful(m))
   }
```

Or even simpler, depending on what it is you are actually testing:

```
   when(repo.create(any)).return(Future.successful(100500))
   when(repo.get(any)).return(Future(mock[Model]))
```

As for passing config values around, something like `(implicit config: Config)` is often used.

Comment: And how can I have a test to create and get value with mocks? Let's say I need to have a test where I create a model and then get that model by id to check if it exists

Comment: @aldm What specifically would you test there? That your repository returns the right model by id? But what's the point in testing that if that repository implementation (in-memory) is't used in production anyway?